# Is there a way to force Xcode's clang to look into /usr/local/include when using a SDK

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, homebrew

I am specifically talking about Xcode's clang, not command line tool's as it sometimes lags behind.

I have boost installed through Homebrew:

```
$ file /usr/local/include/boost/config.hpp 
/usr/local/include/boost/config.hpp: c program text, ASCII text
```

Yet it won't be found:

```
$ xcrun clang++ foo.cpp \ 
   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk \
   -I /usr/local/include

foo.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/config.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/config.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I *need* to use a specific macOS SDK (so with -isysroot) and Xcode's Clang.

Is my only option to install Homebrew elsewhere ?

Comment: try `-I/usr/local/include`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I already have it in my command line, see my post

Comment: No, you have `-I /usr/local/include`

Comment: I just checked and it does not change anything (and I'd be surprised if it did, Clang resolves both to --include-directory=/the/path)

Comment: must be an apple change, standard clang and gcc don't accept spaces: https://godbolt.org/z/xfv5f6f4v

Comment: that's just an issue in godbolt, `g++ -I /usr/local/include` works just fine from the command line (same for clang). Hell, it's even the standard form in man g++: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html (C-f "-I dir")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238589/discussion-between-jean-michael-celerier-and-alan-birtles).